# Type mismatch in LAPACK seemingly resolves itself

Tags: fortran, gfortran, lapack

I am going through some old Fortran code and there are frequent calls to the LAPACK routine dsyevd, which takes an argument IWORK, expected to be an integer array. In this code, IWORK is often declared as a double precision array, and seemingly this has always worked. Indeed if I compare the outputs from dsyevd for IWORK as integer or double precision array the output is equivalent.

I wonder how this can be, given that dsyevd.f as defined [here](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dsyevd.f.html) explicitly declares IWORK as an integer array. Hence I would expect gfortran to give some sort of type mismatch error, but this doesn't happen, and as I indicated the routine works as expected. Of course I will use the proper integer array going forward with this code, but can someone explain to me why this "wrong" code has always worked?

Thanks!

Edit: Some further testing reveals that gfortran 10 does actually report a type mismatch error upon compilation. However gfortran 9 and ifort both compile without issue and seemingly give correct output.

Comment: Do you ever care about the value returned in `iwork`?

Comment: No, its just a workspace array. But I would guess that dsyevd internally cares about the values in iwork

Comment: `iwork(1)` is a returned meaningful value (in some cases). Look at its value when you pass a double precision and when you pass an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legacy Fortran codes, and this includes the LAPACK routines, have only implicit interfaces. That is, the compiler did not (and mostly could not) check the arguments upon a function or subroutine call: it was entirely up to the programmer to make sure he was providing the right arguments.

Now, why is it working fine anyway when the `iwork` actual argument is declared as `double precision` instead of `integer`? Under the hood, what the compiler passes to the routine is just the address of `iwork` in memory, and the routine uses the memory area to temporarily store some integer values.

This could go wrong because of two reasons:

- The actual double precision array `iwork(liwork)` could be smaller in memory than an integer array with the same number of elements, and the routine may then write to memory areas that do not belong to `iwork`. But this is actullay quite the opposite: the Fortran standard specifies that a double precision variable shall occupy exactly twice the storage of an integer variable (typically 64 versus 32 bits, but the standard does not specify a particular size). So no problem here.
- The calling routine would want to use the values returned in `iwork`: this would give garbage values. So if everything works ok, I assume that your code does not use the values output in `iwork` when it is declared as `double precision`

The use of implicit interfaces is still possible in modern Fortran, but the recommendation is to use explicit interfaces (available since Fortran 90).

Comment: The standard _does_ specify particular sizes of default integer and double precision: one and two numeric storage units ;).

Comment: "It" (depending upon exactly what "this" refers to) could also go wrong if the compiler decides, for whatever reason, to "copy in" the double precision actual argument and LWORK is correct for the integer dummy argument.

Comment: @IanBush I'm not sure why it could go wrong in this case. Say `liwork=10`, the double precision `iwork` array occupies 80 bytes, and the copy-in/copy-out makes a hidden temporary of 80 bytes. The routines uses only the first 40 bytes at most. Where is the problem?

Comment: If the called routine only allocates 40 Bytes to copy in to

Comment: The called and calling routines are compiled fully independently (implicit interface). When compiling the calling routine, the compiler has no information on how the called routine has to be called, except that it has to provide an address for `iwork`. The copy-in, if it happens, can then only be triggered from the calling side, and  then 80 bytes are allocated.

Comment: Well, actually the copy-in could be as well be triggered on the called side, my bad. But then only 40 bytes would be allocated AND copied.